# $a^k\equiv b^k\bmod n$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, congruences

$$a,b\in\Bbb Z$$
$$n,k\in\Bbb N^+$$
$$a\equiv b\bmod n$$
$$\text{Use induction to prove}$$
$$a^k\equiv b^k\bmod n$$

Comment: what has been tried ? is this homework ?

Comment: **Hint** $ $ This [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) follows by inductively applying the Congruence Product Rule.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that if $a\equiv b\mod n$ and $c\equiv d\mod n$ then $ac\equiv bd\mod n$?

Comment: Yes, this was proven in an earlier question but i'm stumped with this last bit

Comment: @Kane you have $a\equiv b$ and $a^k\equiv b^k$

Answer (score 3):

The base case is a given.

The successor step follows from

$$x \equiv y \pmod{n} \land x' \equiv y' \pmod{n} \implies xx' \equiv yy' \pmod{n}$$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the induction hypothesis to suppose $a^k\equiv b^k\mod n$. Using the fact that: if $a\equiv b\mod n$ and $c\equiv d\mod n$ then $ac\equiv bd\mod n$ we have:
$$\begin{align}aa^k&\equiv bb^k\mod n\qquad\text{since $a\equiv b\mod n$}\\\implies a^{k+1}&\equiv b^{k+1}\mod n\end{align}$$

Comment: so k is just an arbitrary natural number?

Comment: Yes, $k$ is any natural number. We're inducting on $k$.